# How do I make the Navigation Drawer of my Flutter app transparent?

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

I have built a native Android App which has a transparent navigation drawer. I have been asked to build the same app using Flutter and I have gotten to the point where I would like to implement a transparent navigation drawer. How do I make the Navigation Drawer of my Flutter app transparent because I have been struggling on that end ? I have already tried

```
drawer: Drawer(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,)),
```

The navigation drawer just remains white. I have been searching for a solution to this and cant find one. Any help would be appreciated.
I have attached images of the Native App with a transparent drawer and the Flutter version with a white Navigation drawer

[image: Native]

[image: Flutter]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think there's a better way of doing this without messing up the entire canvases  on the app. Since you want it specifically for the drawer, try this approach.

```
Scaffold(
   drawer: Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
       // Set the transparency here
       canvasColor: Colors.transparent, //or any other color you want. e.g Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5)
      ),
      child: Drawer(
          // All other codes goes here. 
       )
    )
 );
```

Answer (score 7):

use the transparent color like you are currently doing but also in the drawer widget use a stack and inside it make the first widget a backdropfilter, you will need to import dart:ui. here is an example

```
//import this library to use the gaussian blur background
import 'dart:ui';


Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
    ),
    drawer: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.transparent),
        child: sideNav()),
        body: Text('Hello Body'),
),


Drawer sideNav(){
    return Drawer(
        child: Stack(
            children: <Widget> [
                //first child be the blur background
                BackdropFilter(
                    filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5.0, sigmaY: 5.0), //this is dependent on the import statment above
                    child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color.grey.withOpacity(0.5))
                    )
                ),
                ListView(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    children: <Widget>[
                        DrawerHeader(
                            child: Text('Hello Drawer Title')
                        ),
                        ListTitle(
                            leading: Icon(Icons.dashboard, color: Colors.white)
                            title: "Dashboard"
                            onTap: (){

                            }
                        )
                    ]
                )
            ]
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After much tinkering around I managed to find a solution.
I edited the ThemeData and added a canvas color as described below

```
theme: new ThemeData(
   canvasColor: Colors.transparent
 ),
```

This isn't the best way to do this, it is more of a workaround than anything.

[Visual Representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYHKu.png)

Answer (score 0):

[Screenshot Of drawer top whitespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISMdD.png)

If you came here and finding the solution about how to remove the white space above the drawer and status bar then just simply use SingleChildScrollView ---> Column().
Because if you add something like ListView() then the white Space will take place above your drawer which is so irritating to see.
I know this is not the actual solution of this problem but it will help someone who needs it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the drawer with opacity and give the opacity a value (between 0 and 1)

```
Opacity(
  opacity: 0.7,
  child: Drawer(//your drawer here),
),
```